# Contact Form 7 Error: labels and entered values overlaps in the form field. What could be the appropriate solution to this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, material-design, contact-form-7

I am trying to make a contact page for my WordPress site, and have almost completed the form, but I don't know for some reason the **labels and the entered values are getting overlapped with each other when I reload the page after filling the input fields.**

I am using "Contact Form 7" plugin in WordPress, and another extension of this plugin called "Material Design for Contact Form 7", Now, the problem is that I don't know whether this plugin uses Materialize CSS or some other CSS.

Tried alot, but I am unable to figure out the cause of this issue, Is there any solution to this ?

If there's any, **please mention and tell which FILE to edit ? If I need to edit any PHP/CSS/JS file, where can I find it?**

This is what I am getting:

[image: This is what I am getting]

This is what I expect:

[image]

Code used (as instructed by contact form 7 material design plugin extension)

```
[md-form]

[md-text label="House no."]
[text* house-name]
[/md-text]

[md-text label="Street no."]
[text* street-name]
[/md-text]

[md-text label="Post Ofiice"]
[text* po-name]
[/md-text]

[/md-form]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully resolved the issue, finally.

Now it’s working fine, I just edited a few lines of code in

/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/material-design-for-contact-form-7/assets/js/cf7-material-design.js

As instructed/mentioned [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-textfield#pre-filled-text-fields) (Google's Material Design Guidelines) at GitHub

You can see the code

```
$('.cf7md-text, .cf7md-textarea').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                $input = $this.find('input, textarea'),
                $span = $this.find('.wpcf7-form-control-wrap'),
                $tpl = $this.find('.cf7md-text-html').find('> div'),
                $label = $tpl.find('label');

            // I DECLARED THIS VARIABLE
            var text404 = $(this).val();
            // Move input
            $input.detach().prependTo($tpl);
            // Insert template
            $tpl.detach().appendTo($span);
            // Add md class to input
            $input.addClass('mdc-textfield__input');


            // MY CUSTOM CODE STARTS HERE

                if(text404 !== null) {
                    $tpl.addClass('mdc-textfield--upgraded');
                    $label.addClass('mdc-textfield__label--float-above');
                } else {
                //  $this.removeClass('mdc-textfield__input');
                }

            // MY CUSTOM CODE ENDS HERE


            //$if($this.hasValue)
            //$input.addClass('mdc')
            // Add 'for' to label
            $label.attr('for', $input.attr('name'));
            // Add autosize to textareas
            if($this.hasClass('cf7md-textarea-autosize')){
                $input.attr('rows', '2');
                autosize($input);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at the this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) which allows you to design responsive grid-layout designs for contact form 7.